# antialias doesn't work well in three.js

Tags: three.js, antialiasing

I use svg as texture in threee.js, I've already set antialias: true, but still not working perfect,

```
// RENDERER
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            antialias: true, //是否开启反锯齿
            precision: "highp", //着色精度选择
            alpha: true, //是否可以设置背景色透明
            premultipliedAlpha: true,
            stencil: false,
            preserveDrawingBuffer: true, //是否保存绘图缓冲  
            maxLights: 1 //maxLights:最大灯光数
        });

renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
```

this is svg:
[image: svg picture]

this is texture on 3d model:
[image: texture]

could anybody help me?

thanks!

Comment: It would be better if you show an working code with the problem. For example, on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

When an image is loaded into a 3d environment it is not pixels but defined as texels. Texels are translated to the space available on a face as set by the UV coordinates. The original image is sampled according to the sample method you supply. Some result in specifically blocky looks. Think minecraft. Others are very smooth and especially blurry when zoomed in. Think older video games.

To determine the sample method of your original image you can set the sample technique in the magnification and minification properties of the texutre.

Try

```
    mySVG = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('assets/images/icons/mySVG.svg');
    mySVG.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
    mySVG.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter;
```

Various filters are available and documented at https://threejs.org/docs/api/textures/Texture.html